# SSRS report is taking more time for 3000 records

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to run a report which has around 5000 records.
The report contains a table and there is 1 grouping grouping in the table.

My stored proc takes 20 seconds to run but the report takes around 3 minutes.
The report is around 120 pages with around 30 records on each page.

Is this the time the report will take to run or am I missing something.

I will have more than 50,000 records in this report in future. So, I need to know if there is anything I can do for it.

I have the following code which will run for a particular column in each row:

`Function FormatTimer(ByVal seconds As Object) As Object
        Dim retVal As Object
        Dim days As Integer
        Dim hours As Integer
        Dim minutes As Integer`

```
    If IsNothing(seconds) Then
        retVal = ""
    Else
        retVal = ""

        days = Abs(seconds) \ 86400
        seconds = seconds - days * 86400

        hours = Abs(seconds) \ 3600
        seconds = seconds - hours * 3600

        minutes = Abs(seconds) \ 60
        seconds = seconds - minutes * 60

        If days &gt; 0 Then retVal = days.ToString() + "d "

        retVal = retVal + Format(hours, "00") + ":" + Format(minutes, "00") + ":" + Format(seconds, "00")
    End If

    FormatTimer = retVal
```

End Function

When I remove this code , my report renders much faster, almost 30 seconds.
If I use functions like this in each row, will it effect the performance this much?

I have group by also in my report which looks like below:

Fields!PatientName.Value & "   " &  Fields!MRN.Value & "  "& Fields!VisitNumber.Value

I have also attached how my report will look like.

[image]

Please let me know what can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Just my opinion but if you really need to create a 120 pages report, recreate a stored version on a daily basis and provide filtered reports for realtime viewing. I doubt anyone will want read a full 120 pages report with just-in-time data.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to identify the time it takes for a report to generate is to query the Reporting Services database.

In the reporting services database there's a table called the ExecutionLog. This table records details about every report run including the time it takes to generate the report.

More importantly the table provides a detailed breakdown of the time it takes to generate a report...it records duration for TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, and TimeRendering.

This will help you in identifying which phase of report execution is taking the most time.

If the stored proc takes 20 seconds to bring back a full dataset then chances are the time is because of either calculations, lookups etc. done in the table of the report, or simply the time it takes to render that much information.

Edit: Looking at the executionlog table will help you to identify the issue, but it won't solve your problem with regards to the time it takes for your report to run. Once you identify the issue try and resolve it or post the problem back here when you have a better understanding of what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, I just added a sample report with the same data but this time I have 40,000 records. I am just rendering the data in the table. The time has hugely reduced to just 1 minutes. So, it seems that I need to work on the report and remove all the processing to stored proc. But with 40,000 records, I have 2200 pages. Will any one read this huge data?

Comment: That is something that you need to find out from your users. You might want to make it an interactive report where users enter in parameters, you will need to change the stored proc as well to take in parameters, but filtering the data will reduce the run time and the data returned. What Filburt suggested is also worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Page Break? just a thought.

> You can add a page break to rectangles, data regions, or groups within data regions to control the amount of information on each page. Adding page breaks can improve the performance of published reports because only the items on each page have to be processed as you view the report. When the whole report is a single page, all items must be processed before you can view the report.